# On the need to convert all atoms into single-item lists when looping

Tags: list, loops, common-lisp

Given the nested list below that represents a tree structure,

```
(A (B 1 (2 f g)) C (D 3 4) E)
```

The following function would give all top-level elements in the list only if `A` `C` and `E` are all coded as single-item lists.

```
((A) (B 1 (2 f g)) (C) (D 3 4) (E))

(defun top-level-elm (lst)
  (loop for x from 0 to (- (length lst) 1)
     collect (car (nth x lst))))

(top-level-elm '((A) (B 1 (2 f g)) (C) (D 3 4) (E)))

;; Result: (A B C D E)
```

If we were to try looping within the nested lists to find the top-level items for each, we would run into the problem of having to store the data in a format that has many parentheses, which not only is inelegant but can also easily lead to error.

```
(defun elm-id (elm lst)
  (position elm (top-level-elm lst)))

(top-level-elm (child-of (nth 3 (top-level-elm lst)) lst))

;; Error Msg: The value 3 is not of type LIST
```

Instead of having to rewrite the data like this:

```
((A) ((B) (1) ((2) (f) (g))) (C) ((D) (3) (4)) (E))
```

Is there a more elegant way of coding?

---

## Updated Function:

With reference to @coredump's answer below, I've updated the above `top-level-elm` function as follows:

```
(defun top-level-elm (tree)
  (loop for i from 0 to (- (length tree) 1)
     collect (elt (elt (normalize-tree tree) i) 0)))
```

Please check if I've got it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way of coding?

You need first to define your format clearly.

Then you have basically two options: make sure all your functions handle the different corner cases that can be used to represent a tree, or define an internal data format that is more regular (but less user-friendly); in that case, you normalize/sanitize first your inputs, and then you work on the normalized data. Both are valid, but it is the second approach that is demonstrated here.

So here you want to be able to write a tree as follows:

```
(A (B 1 (2 f g)) C (D 3 4) E)
```

This is an external format. From your descriptions, you define a tree as follows:

*A tree is a list `(T1 ... Tn)` where `T1` to `Tn` are either subtrees or atoms (data); the simplified notation `A` where A is a non-nil atom represents the tree `(A)`; NIL is an empty tree.*

Let's define a helper function that, given an input tree provided by the user, normalizes the data to make it into a regular shape; your other functions can then assume a tree is always normalized, which simplifies further processing.

In order to define normalized tree, I'll use vectors, so that it is clearly distinct from the external format: *a normalized tree is a vector containing either nested normalized trees, or atoms*.

A vector in Common Lisp is a one-dimensional array; it can be accessed in constant time with `elt` and its size can be retrieve in constant time too. Your code on the other hands, calls `length` and `nth` on lists, but both operations are linear in time for those data-structures, which makes iterations over those lists slower than necessary:

> ```
> (defun top-level-elm (lst)
>   (loop for x from 0 to (- (length lst) 1)
>      collect (car (nth x lst))))
> ```
>
> `length` must traverse the whole list, which is unfortunate but not catastrophic; but each `nth` also needs a linear traversal, and since you are doing it in a loop, that gives a quadratic complexity O(n^2) for the whole loop.

With a vector representation for normalized tree, you can keep your original approach where you visit children by their index.

So here is how you would iterate over the user-provided tree and return a normalized tree:

```
(defun normalize-tree (tree)
  (typecase tree
    (list (map 'vector #'normalize-tree tree))
    (t (vector tree))))
```

In case the input is a list, you map each child to its normalized form, aggregating the result in a vector. In case the input is not a list, it is necessarily a non-nil atom, and it is normalized as a singleton vector holding that value.

With your example tree, that would give:

```
(normalize-tree
 '(A (B 1 (2 f g)) C (D 3 4) E))

=> #(#(A) #(#(B) #(1) #(#(2) #(F) #(G))) #(C) #(#(D) #(3) #(4)) #(E))
```

Fortunately, the normalized format needs not to be shown to the user, it is only an internal format that is useful to you. In fact, you could also take a normalized tree and output it in a simplified way.

This is the reverse operation, where you can assume the input is a vector; you then recursively map all its element (either atoms or norm-trees) to their simplified form, aggregate the result in a list, and, if that list only contains one element, represent it by its first element.

```
(defun simplify-normalized-tree (tree)
  (flet ((simplify-item (item)
           (typecase item
             (vector (simplify-normalized-tree item))
             (t item))))
    (let ((simplified (map 'list #'simplify-item tree)))
      (if (rest simplified)
          simplified
          (first simplified)))))
```

For example:

```
(simplify-normalized-tree
 (normalize-tree '(A (B 1 (2 f g)) C (D 3 4) E)))

=> (A (B 1 (2 F G)) C (D 3 4) E)
```

You could take the whole idea of internal data even more in depth, and define two classes, `leaf` and `node`, both subclasses of a `tree` class, where `node` holds a vector of child trees and `leaf` holds an arbitrary data. Then, processing a tree could be done in terms of generic functions, etc. This is not always desirable to have such complexity, but in larger projects this may be useful.